# jquery charts from returned json data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I have got json data out of my database using mysql and php and now would like to pass it back using $.ajax function and create a spline charts out of it dynamically any help or examples will be appreciated.  also for multiple blood test the date repeated, how can i show only one date with multiple blood test results.

here is my php code

```
header('Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-type: application/json');
require_once"conn.php";

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){

//recieve credentials from the user 
$nhsno = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['pnhsno']);

//check the variables recieved are not empty
    if($nhsno != ''){

        $sql = "SELECT date,name,tname,value FROM examination e, testresults t, examtype ex, testname tn
        WHERE e.patientnhs_no = '$nhsno' and e.etype_id = '1' and
        e.examination_id = t.examination_id and e.etype_id = ex.etype_id and t.tname_id = tn.tname_id ";//create an sql statement 
        $result = $conn->query($sql);//run sqlm statement 
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); //fetch row of data


    foreach ($result as $row){
        $return[]=array('date'=>$row['date'],
                        'name'=>$row['name'],
                        'test name'=>$row['tname'],
                        'value'=>$row['value']);
    }
}
}
$conn = null;
echo json_encode($return);


?>
```

and here is my json output

```
[{"date":"2004-07-05","name":"blood test","test name":"t3","value":"6.8"},  {"date":"2004-07-05","name":"blood test","test name":"t4","value":"29"},{"date":"2004-07-05","name":"blood test","test name":"tsh","value":"0.01"},{"date":"2004-07-05","name":"blood test","test name":"thyroglobulin level","value":"0.5"},{"date":"2005-06-15","name":"blood test","test name":"t3","value":"5.2"},{"date":"2005-06-15","name":"blood test","test name":"t4","value":"30"},{"date":"2005-06-15","name":"blood test","test name":"tsh","value":"0.02"},{"date":"2005-06-15","name":"blood test","test name":"thyroglobulin level","value":"0.5"}]
```

Comment: Which library are you using to create the charts...

Comment: canvas jquery charts

Comment: charts.js or any other that I can get a spline chart

Comment: You need to contruct your json response depending on the javascript library that you are going to use...see this sample: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/spline-symbols/

Answer (score 0):

Because you mixing a lot of things, and you fetch 1 row before the loop.

It should be something like this:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql); //run sqlm statement 
//Do not need this!
//$row = $result->fetch_assoc(); //fetch row of data
//And $row = $result... not opposite.
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $return[] = array('date' => $row['date'],
        'name' => $row['name'],
        'test name' => $row['tname'],
        'value' => $row['value']);
}
```